# Why is this question in the Top Questions / active list?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A couple of minutes ago I stumbled upon [**this question**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37463/storing-the-data-twice-on-save). The reasons I'm asking this question are:

- There has been no activity since [**Jamal♦**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal) last edited it.
- It has been migrated from SO, altough it's a question concerning broken code.
- In the question list it says it has been modified by the community user

[image]

So why is an inactive, off-topic question (re-)appearing in the top list?

Answer (score 7):

As you can see, it says "modified 1 hour ago" by Community.

The reason for this can be found [in this meta.stackexchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190583/community-what-are-you-doing/190584#190584)

Short version: Community user randomly pings old, unanswered questions to give them more attention and a better chance at an answer.

Comment: Migrated Dec.8, closed/rejected yesterday?? That one really slipped through!